# MATLAB - plot a vector using different line style

Tags: graphing-functions, matlab

I have an array where the first column is the data I want to plot and the second column contains either 1 or -1 to indicate stability. I want to plot the portions of the data marked as '1' with a dashed line, but the rest with a solid line. How do I do this without ending up with the two lines being disconnected? Is there a neat way?

Answer (score 0):

First extract to vectors, the ones associated with -1, and 1 with :

```
 dashed = your_Vector(find(your_Vector(:, 2) == 1))
 solid  = your_Vector(find(your_Vector(:, 2) == -1 ))
```

and then plot as you wish.

Comment: Thanks, but my difficulty is plotting the two vectors so they form a continuous line. What I'm expecting to see is a line that starts solid, turn dashed, then goes solid again. It's this aspect, rather than separating the original vector, that I'm struggling with.

Comment: Maybe you could try to play with marker indices as indicated here : http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/create-line-plot-with-markers.html, I don't know if you can do it with dashed/solid line though. Another solution would be to plot everything dashed, and then on the same plot, above the dashed line redraw the sections you want solid. If you keep track of your abscissas you should be able to handle it.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the advice. I've decided to settle with, as you say, just plotting solid segments over a dashed line.